# how to save value in listview from other form

Tags: c#, visual-studio, listview

Im having a problem in my listview because whenever I get value in other form it is not adding on the list but when I put breakpoint it have a value but still not adding on my listview.

here is my function in form1 getting values from datagridview

```
public void dataGridView1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        qtyOfOrders orders = new qtyOfOrders();
        if (dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
        {
            String mealname = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value + String.Empty;
            String price1 = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[2].Value + String.Empty;
            pts.meal = mealname;
            pts.qtyprice = Int32.Parse(price1);
            orders.Show();
        }
    }
```

here is my function from form2 and will save data in listview in form1

```
private void OK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cashier c = new cashier();
        pricetempstorage pts = new pricetempstorage(); //class
            int qty = Int32.Parse(QTYNumber.Text);
            int totalPrice = qty * pts.qtyprice;
        pts.qtynumber = qty;
        pts.TotalPrice = totalPrice;
        c.listView1.Items.Add(pts.meal);
        c.qtyOrder.ListView.Items[0].SubItems.Add(pts.qtynumber.ToString());
       c.price111.ListView.Items[0].SubItems.Add(pts.TotalPrice.ToString());
        this.Hide();
    }
```

this is my class

```
namespace jollibee4
{
class pricetempstorage
{
    static int qtyNumber;
    static int qtyPrice;
    static  int ListViewCount;
    static String Meal;
    static int totalprice;
    public int TotalPrice
    {
        get
        {
            return totalprice;
        }
        set
        {
            totalprice = qtyNumber * qtyPrice;
        }
    }
    public int qtynumber
    {
        get
        {
            return qtyNumber;
        }
        set
        {
            qtyNumber = value;
        }
    }
    public int qtyprice
    {
        get
        {
            return qtyPrice;
        }
        set
        {
            qtyPrice = value;
        }
    }
    public int listviewCount
    {
        get
        {
            return ListViewCount;
        }
        set
        {
            ListViewCount = value;
        }
    }
    public String meal
    {
        get
        {
            return Meal;
        }
        set
        {
            Meal = value;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**form1**

```
    public List<pricetempstorage> Items { get; private set; }

    private void OK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            cashier c = new cashier();
            pricetempstorage pts = new pricetempstorage(); //class
            int qty = Int32.Parse(QTYNumber.Text);
            int totalPrice = qty * pts.qtyprice;
            pts.qtynumber = qty;
            pts.TotalPrice = totalPrice;
            Items.Add(pts);
            this.Hide();
        }
```

Create a shopping cart class where items can be append in list
I assume pricetempstorage is your class of item, its name can be product

```
    public static ShoppingCart GetInstance()
    {

        if (cart == null)
        {
            cart = new ShoppingCart();
        }

        return cart;
    }

    protected ShoppingCart()
    {
        Items = new List<pricetempstorage>();
    }
```

Comment: I created the class of ShoppingCart, but I got error on the word `Session (Session does not exist in current context)`, Items also got an error` (An object reference is required)`

Comment: i have modified it,

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this code `this.listView1.View = View.Details;` After the  `c.listView1.Items.Add(pts.meal);`

Comment: Does it containing existing data before you add it? If so try clear the list before adding to the list

Answer (score 0):

You have many architectural and stylistic issues with your program (use of static, capitalization, etc.)--to correct them all would require a very lengthy response.

Your code isn't working because you're creating a new instance of the cashier class, and then you're updating its listView1 object. What I think you're trying to do is update the listView object of Form2. So what you should be doing is grabbing a reference to Form2 and populating its ListView object in your OK_Click event handler...

Just a tip here: Public properties should have an initial capital letter. Your pricetempstorage class needs some work.